# kropholler's conjecture and $3$-manifolds group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds

Suppose that $G$ is a group and that $H$ is a subgroup, both finitely generated, and assume that there is a non-trivial $H$-almost invariant set $X$ with $HXH=X$. Kropholler's Conjecture asserts that $ G $ splits over a subgroup commensurable with a subgroup of $H$.

Note that the algebraic hypothesis $HXH= X $ can be reformulated in terms of strong crossings - see "Splittings of Groups and Intersection Numbers" by Peter Scott and Gadde A. Swarup.

There is a paper of M.Sageev which proves the conjecture for quasiconvex subgroups of hyperbolic groups. My question is this: is the result true for $3$-manifold groups and surface subgroups?
Author :zeraoulia rafik

I would like someone to give me some explanation (link, paper,..) about this strange problem. Thank you for your replies or any comments.

Comment: It seems that the question was answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168648/krophollers-conjecture-and-3-manifolds. Do you have a problem with the answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because: A fully satisfactory answer was already given at Mathoverflow. Asking it again here makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper of Scott and Swarup mentioned in the question cites Kropholler and Roller's '
Splittings of Poincaré duality groups'. On page 35 they write

let $ K $ be a Poincaré duality group of dimension $n-1$ which is a subgroup of a Poincaré

duality group $ G $ of dimension $n$...Kropholler and Roller defined an obstruction $sing(K)$

to splitting $ G $ over a subgroup commensurable with $ K $..they showed that $sing(K)$

vanishes if and only if there is a $ K $-Almost invariant subset $ Y $ of $ G $  such that 
$KYK=Y$

Taking n=3, this seems to answer your question.

Comment: This is all utterly bizarre: It seems that OP is answering his own question by copying an answer by HJRW given at Mathoverflow.

Comment: hi , it's my question in mathoverflow, just want other answer , i'm not understand the answer that i received in mathoverflow , thanks

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Then ask a question _about_ that answer: the parts of it do you not understand. Or even ask a question in a comment to HJRW's answer on MathOverflow seeking clarification.  (BTW: it appears that you have created at least two accounts. To have them merged please [follow the directions here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).)

Comment: @rafik: please attribute the author when you copy someone else's post. Otherwise, this is [plagiarism](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and that is reason for suspension.

Comment: i'm posted this question  in mathoverflow , it's mine post